# Partially hyperbolic systems and specification

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $f: M \rightarrow M$ be a $C^{1+\alpha}$ diffeomorphism on a Riemannian compact manifold. Suppose that $f$ admits a dominated splitting $T M=E \oplus F$ with $E\ll F$, where $E$ is uniformly contracting.

I would like to know that under what (minimal) assumptions $f$ satisfies the specification property. As Sumi, Varandas, and Yamamoto showed in [Specification and partial hyperbolicity for flows](https://doi.org/10.1080/14689367.2015.1081380), we don't necessarily have specification property for partially hyperbolic systems.